# Cannot load tun module

Tags: kernel-modules, vpn, openvpn

I cannot manage to load the tun module in my Arch Linux box. I'm trying
to connect with openvpn, but the log says

> nm-openvpn[6662]: Note: Cannot open TUN/TAP dev /dev/net/tun: No such device (errno=19)

```
lsmod | grep tun
```

returns nothing.

If I run

```
sudo modprobe tun
```

it returns failure, but no error message, and lsmod still has no tun. The module seems to exist, as there is a tun.ko.gz in /lib/modules/.......

I really don't know what else to try.

Comment: Try an `insmod` on the path of the `tun.ko` and look at the `dmesg` output.

Comment: What happens if you `insmod` the module manually?

Comment: How do I do that? I tried insmod /path/to/tun.ko.gz, I got "Invalid module format", I unzipped it and tried again and got the same

Answer (score 1):

Contact your VPS provider and ask them to enable it. Many OpenVZ-based VPS providers disable TUN/TAP unless specifically requested by the customer.